# When I click pay now at ESTA the page information disappeared. What now?

Tags: esta, payment

After I click  PAY now at ESTA I couldn't write any payment details. There was no information, it just sends me to the initial page. Should I wait for a response and then pay, or should I start all over again?

Comment: You probably took too long to complete the process. Try again.

Comment: Really an IT /website question, not a travel question, sorry :/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for support of a government website tech issue.